# How to add / update / remove relation in feathers sequelize

Tags: feathersjs, feathers-sequelize

I try to use feathers to create a blog with Post and Tag (Many to Many relationship). If I create Post and Tag separate and `add / update / remove` relations. What should I do?

Here is my github repo
https://github.com/kieusonlam/blogapi

Comment: id you get anywhere ?